# recursive function: No instance (Num) arising from the literal

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a recursive function which defines division in terms of subtraction. So I have created a new type "DividedResult" to take into account a "divide by zero" case. Do my datatype declaration and function type declaration make sense? I get such errors:

```
No instance for (Num DividedResult) arising from the literal `0' In the third argument of `go'
```

```
Could not deduce (Num DividedResult) arising from a use of `+'
```

(Probably have to create a Num instance? I have tried, but it doesn't work for me).
Here is my code:

```
data DividedResult = Result Integer | DividedByZero

dividedBy :: Integer -> Integer -> (DividedResult, Integer)
dividedBy num denom = go num denom 0
  where go n d count
         | d == 0 = (DividedByZero, n)
         | abs n < abs d = (count, n)
         | abs n >= abs d && n > 0 && d > 0 = go (n - d) d (count + 1)
         | abs n >= abs d && n > 0 && d < 0 = go (n + d) d (count - 1)
         | abs n >= abs d && n < 0 && d < 0 = go (n - d) d (count + 1)
         | abs n >= abs d && n < 0 && d > 0 = go (n + d) d (count - 1)
```

Comment: `| abs n < abs d = (Result count, n)`

Comment: When the error is confusing, add more type annotations. Here, annotating `go` would point out that `.... = (count, n)` has the wrong type, and needs `Result`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get that error, is because you are trying to return an actual Integer here:

```hs
| abs n < abs d = (count, n)
```

By returning `count`, an `Integer` instead of a `DividedResult`, the compiler thinks you are trying to cast a number into a `DividedResult`, which is only possible if `DividedResult` is a `Num`

In this case, making `DividedResult` an instance of `Num` would be overkill; you just need to wrap `count`:

```hs
| abs n < abs d = (Result count, n)
```